# FirstOrDefault seems to not evaluate or condition

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin.forms

I'm actually facing a problem that I really don't understand.
The scenario is quite simple:

I'm developing a cross-platform application with `Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0` and I need to filter the elements inside an `ObservableCollection` with `Linq`.
The collection is composed by elements which have two sub elements (left and right) of the same type.
Here you are the portion of code that creates me problems:

```
var element = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Left.Item.Id == searchId || e.Right.Item.Id == searchId);
```

If the requested id is the same of the left element (so the first to be evaluated in the or condition) everything is fine, but if I request an Id which is equal to the one of the right element, `FirstOrDefault` returns null, like the condition is short-circuited by the first statement. I've also tried to separate the operations, putting the condition inside a Where function, before the `FirstOrDefault`, but nothing changes.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit
Sorry, here you are more code

```
class MyClass{
  ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection {get; set;}

  public MyClass(List<MyItem> list){
     MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
     MyCollection.ItemSource = list;
  }

  public void MyMethod(Guid searchId, string newName){
     var element = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Left.Item.Id == searchId || e.Right.Item.Id == searchId);
      //more code which is not relevant
     }


}

class MyItem{
public Item Left {get; set;}
public Item Right {get; set;}
}

class Item{
public Guid Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You will need to add more code. What type is `Id`? Is it the same type as `searchId`? Short circuiting doesn't apply on your OR statement unless the first expression evaluates to true - so if the first is false then the second will be evaluated.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] because your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've added more example code

Comment: @AnuViswan example code, just edited with the right visibility, sorry

Comment: @PaoloArdissone Did you try separating the query into 2 separate queries? One for left and one for right elements? Does that work?

Comment: Instead of `e.Left.Item.Id` did you intended to write `e.Left.Id`? There is no property `Item` in the classes you have shown.

Comment: We need a [mcve] **that compiles standalone** and we can run at our end to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the cause of this issue.

The problem is that xamarin.forms doesn't reload the deployed application properly with just a rebuild of the solution.

The lambda expression inside the FirstOrDefault at first was only

```
e => e.Left.Item.Id == searchId
```

instead of

```
e => e.Left.Item.Id == searchId || e.Right.Item.Id == searchId
```

To solve these kind of problems, every time you modify the xaml or the cs, you have to rebuild the entire solution (or only the involved projects) and delete manually the application from the device/emulator.

It doesn't occur every time, but I thins is a necessary practice to avoid these problems.

I hope this will help someone else